# Sorting on a count field in web2py

Tags: sorting, web2py

I have the following code in web2py. I am trying to retrieve how many types of items I have in the table and a count of how many of each of them there are.

```
count = db.table.field1.count()
rows=db((some criteria).select(db.table.field2, count, groupby=db.table.field2)
print rows
```

The print of this is:

```
table.field2, COUNT(table.field1)
4,3
6,4
9,2
```

Now I would like to sort from high to low by the count field, so the outcome would be:

```
6,4
4,3
9,2
```

What's the best way to do it? rows=rows.sort(lambda row: row.COUNT(table.field1)) did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `row.COUNT(table.field1)`, use `row['COUNT(table.field1)']` or just `row[count]` (see [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Grouping-and-counting)).

Note, you can also have the database do the sorting using the `orderby` argument:

```
rows = db(query).select(db.table.field2, count,
                        groupby=db.table.field2, orderby=count)
```

And for descending order: `orderby=~count`